# JAVA Procedure Error

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

**java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Procedure 'STP_Insert_tblReceipt' expects parameter '@CPVFlag', which was not supplied.**

I m getting error at This Point when trying to call procedure...
Everything is perfect ,,,Count of Question marks are similar to parameter provided

```
cs = conn.prepareCall("{call STP_Insert_tblReceipt(?,?,?,  ?,?,?,  ?,?,?,  ?,?,?,  ?,?,?, ?,?,?, ?,?,?, ?,?,?, ?,?,?)}");
// cs = conn.prepareCall("{call STP_Receipt_Form_Insertion_Trial(?,?,?,  ?,?,?,  ?,?,?,  ?,?,?,  ?)}");
cs.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(txtMobileNo.getText()));
cs.setString(2, String.valueOf(cboDistributor.getSelectedItem()));
cs.setLong(3, Long.parseLong(txtBoxNo.getText()));
cs.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(txtFileNo.getText()));
cs.setString(5, pickUp_date);
cs.setString(6, rec_date);
cs.setString(7, String.valueOf(cmbCtrlNo.getSelectedItem()));
cs.setString(8, UserName);
cs.setString(9, rec_date);
cs.setString(10, RegionLocation);
cs.setString(11, txtRemark.getText().trim());
cs.setString(12, txtSimNo.getText().trim());
cs.setInt(13, 2);
cs.setString(14, String.valueOf(cmbAryanRegion.getSelectedItem()));
cs.setString(15, String.valueOf(cboPickUpType.getSelectedItem()));
cs.setString(16, String.valueOf(txtCafNo.getText()));
cs.setString(17, distributorId);
//cs.setString(18, circleName);
cs.setString(18, cboCircle.getSelectedItem().toString());
cs.registerOutParameter(19, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cs.setString(20, auditorName);
cs.setString(21, retailerName);
cs.setString(22, retailerCode);
cs.setInt(23, mappedFlag);
//cs.setString(24, distCode);
cs.setString(24, cboDistCode.getSelectedItem().toString());
//cs.setString(25, zoneName);
cs.setString(25, cboZone.getSelectedItem().toString());
cs.setString(26, comment);
**cs.setInt(27, 1);** **this is for CPV Flag**
```

After this cs.execute();

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a parameter in the `?` list...

Comment: Please post the signature of the SQL stored procedure for our reference.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Procedure 'STP_Insert_tblReceipt' expects parameter '@CPVFlag', which was not supplied......This is Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the definition of the proc with SQL parameter list. 
Check the proc, most likely the error is at:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(19, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

The variable may be an in-out parameter.